# How to reduce time and space complexity of the following code

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

Optimize (Reduce the space and Time complexity)this function as much as possible.

```
  public void q1(String str, int[] arr)
  {    
        String local = "findnumber"; 
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        { 
            if(str.equals(local) && arr[i] * 2 > 10)
            { 
                Integer in = new Integer(arr[i]);    
                in = in * 2; 
                System.out.print(in.toString());
            } 
        } 
   }
```

Comment: Well there's only one str so you can put the for loop in an str if block and the for won't run unless the str equals the string defined

Comment: How is this related to android?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like homework but I'll bite. Here's what I got...

- `str.equals(local)` can be calculated outside the loop (and may stop you entering the loop at all)
- You can store the value of `arr[i]` to stop it being looked up
  multiple times
- Why create an Integer from i when you are just doing maths on it?
- `in *= 2` is theoretically faster than `in = in * 2` (or `i` if you kill `in` as above)
- Since all you ever use is `arr[i] * 2`, calculate that once and use it in the `if` as well as the output. (no need for the `in=in*2` or `in*=2` at all)
- Buffer up the output and just have one output statement at the end of
  the loop.

Comment: `in` left shift is the same as `*2`

Comment: @SteveKuo true. Could even be faster (I haven't gone to that level in the JVM specs). I don't do it because a) I think it makes the code less readable/obvious and b) the difference between `i=i*2`, `i*=2` and `i<<2` doesn't often matter in the real world ;-)

Comment: I don't see how any of these changes the complexity of anything.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the first 2 are about the same, `i<<2` is something (that in my experience) not everyone gets. People from a Comp Sci background get it but others with different backgrounds generally know it is a shift, but don't have that understanding of what it ends up doing.